# bz2 decompress with Python 3.4 - TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python, python-3.4, bzip2

There are similar errors but I could not find a solution for bz2.

The following program fails on the decompress:

```
import bz2

un =  'BZh91AY&SYA\xaf\x82\r\x00\x00\x01\x01\x80\x02\xc0\x02\x00 \x00!\x9ah3M\x07<]\xc9\x14\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084'
pw =  'BZh91AY&SY\x94$|\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x81\x00\x03$ \x00!\x9ah3M\x13<]\xc9\x14\xe1BBP\x91\xf08'
decoded_un = bz2.decompress(un)
decoded_pw = bz2.decompress(pw)

print(decoded_un)
print(decoded_pw)
```

I tried using `bytes(un, 'UTF-8)` but that would not work. I think I did not have this problem in Python 3.3.

EDIT: this was for the Python challenge I have two bits of code which work thanks to Martijn:

```
import bz2

un_saved =  'BZh91AY&SYA\xaf\x82\r\x00\x00\x01\x01\x80\x02\xc0\x02\x00 \x00!\x9ah3M\x07<]\xc9\x14\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084'
pw_saved =  'BZh91AY&SY\x94$|\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x81\x00\x03$ \x00!\x9ah3M\x13<]\xc9\x14\xe1BBP\x91\xf08'
print(bz2.decompress(un_saved.encode('latin1')))
print(bz2.decompress(pw_saved.encode('latin1')))
```

This one works from the webpage:

```
# http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/integrity.html

import urllib.request
import re
import os.path
import bz2

fname = "008.html"

if not os.path.isfile(fname):
    url = 'http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/integrity.html'
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    webpage = response.read().decode("utf-8")
    with open(fname, "w") as fh:
        fh.write(webpage)

with open(fname, "r") as fh:
    webpage = fh.read()
    re_un = '\\nun: \'(.*)\'\\n'
    m = re.search(re_un, webpage)
    un = m.group(1)
    print(un)

    pw_un = '\\npw: \'(.*)\'\\n'
    m = re.search(pw_un, webpage)
    pw = m.group(1)
    print(pw)

    unde = un.encode('latin-1').decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin1')
    pwde = pw.encode('latin-1').decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin1')
    decoded_un = bz2.decompress(unde)
    decoded_pw = bz2.decompress(pwde)

    print(decoded_un)
    print(decoded_pw)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bz2` library deals with *`bytes` objects*, not strings:

```
un = b'BZh91AY&SYA\xaf\x82\r\x00\x00\x01\x01\x80\x02\xc0\x02\x00 \x00!\x9ah3M\x07<]\xc9\x14\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084'
pw = b'BZh91AY&SY\x94$|\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x81\x00\x03$ \x00!\x9ah3M\x13<]\xc9\x14\xe1BBP\x91\xf08'
```

In other words, using `bytes()` works just fine, just make sure you use the correct encoding. UTF-8 is not that encoding; if you have bytes masking as string character codepoints, use Latin-1 to encode instead; Latin 1 maps characters one-on-one to bytes:

```
un = un.encode('latin1')
```

or

```
un = bytes(un, 'latin1')
```

Also see the [Python *Unicode HOWTO*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html):

> Latin-1, also known as ISO-8859-1, is a similar encoding. Unicode code points 0–255 are identical to the Latin-1 values, so converting to this encoding simply requires converting code points to byte values; if a code point larger than 255 is encountered, the string can’t be encoded into Latin-1.

I'll leave the decoding to you. Have fun with the Python Challenge!

Note that if you loaded these characters *as they are* from a webpage, they will **not** by ready-made bytes! You'll have the characters `'\'`, `'x'`, `8` and `2` rather than a codepoint with hex value 82. You'd need to interpret those sequences as a Python string literal first:

```
>>> un = r'BZh91AY&SYA\xaf\x82\r\x00\x00\x01\x01\x80\x02\xc0\x02\x00 \x00!\x9ah3M\x07<]\xc9\x14\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084'
>>> un
'BZh91AY&SYA\\xaf\\x82\\r\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x01\\x80\\x02\\xc0\\x02\\x00 \\x00!\\x9ah3M\\x07<]\\xc9\\x14\\xe1BA\\x06\\xbe\\x084'
>>> un.encode('latin-1').decode('unicode_escape')
'BZh91AY&SYA¯\x82\r\x00\x00\x01\x01\x80\x02À\x02\x00 \x00!\x9ah3M\x07<]É\x14áBA\x06¾\x084'
>>> un.encode('latin-1').decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin1')
b'BZh91AY&SYA\xaf\x82\r\x00\x00\x01\x01\x80\x02\xc0\x02\x00 \x00!\x9ah3M\x07<]\xc9\x14\xe1BA\x06\xbe\x084'
```

Note the *double* backslashes in the representation of `un`. Only the last `bytes` result is then decompressable!

Comment: Do you have a link I could use to understand the different encoding ? I am really struggling with this ... This was for the Python Challenge ...

Comment: @BlueTrin: yeah, I recognised the strings. Not sure if I have a link for you, but take into account that the challenge was written for Python 2, before Python 3 was mainstream.

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: less helpful in this context, where the bytes are taken from a webpage but whatever extraction method used by the OP gave them a string rather than bytes..

Comment: @BlueTrin: I suspect there was something else wrong here, I updated the answer. In future, can you make sure you always include the *full error* you got with the code you tried?

Comment: I was trying to figure out by myself how to solve reading from the webpage. I ended up writing the same thing than in your solution.